# Facebook photo shows on timeline but not in Photos

Tags: facebook-timeline, facebook-photos

There is a photo on Facebook timeline posted in 2012 (person not in my friend list). However the photo does not appear in Photos nor in the Album it is tagged in (earlier it use to appear in the album).

The album count says 13 photos and those 13 photos does not include the photo in question (or else it should have read 14 photos but it reads only 13).

The photo does continue to appear on timeline (the post is Public)

What does that mean? Has the user made any changes and if yes, what are they? [image]